# NGINX: Allow multiple ports to be available for https + redirect all http to https

Tags: linux, redirect, nginx, https

I'm trying to deploy an NGINX server that hosts two node.js Express apps over https.

My main site (the one to be served on port 80) is an Express app running on port 8001. (i.e. https://example.com loads this app)

I'm also running another Express app on port 8002 that I want to be available publicly on port 8080. (i.e. https://example.com:8080 loads this app)

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  # SSL configuration
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  # Pass requests for / to localhost:8001:
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8080 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

  include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  # pass requests to port 8002 where our other node server is running
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8002/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

If it's of any additional assistance, I've been following the DigitalOcean guides for configuring https and NGINX
[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)
and
[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: @FarhadFarahi The problem is trying to access `http://example.com:8080` or `https://example.com:8080` from public results in a timeout without a response.

Hitting those same routes locally (`curl` from the server itself), returns success on the https route, but `400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port` for the http route.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;` from 3rd server block.